# Getting error 'Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "…82 4.643-4.643c0-z".'

Tags: svg

I am trying to use the following value for a 'path'.
"M12.768 6.5c0 3.46-2.807 6.268-6.268 6.268s-6.268-2.807-6.268-6.268c0-3.148 2.321-5.753 5.339-6.203v1.654c-2.118 0.428-3.714 2.307-3.714 4.549 0 2.561 2.082 4.643 4.643 4.643s-4.643-2.082 4.643-4.643c0-z".

But I'm getting an error saying
'Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "…82 4.643-4.643c0-z".'

Can someone please tell me what is the issue in this 'd' value

Answer (score 0):

The [c command](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands) must be followed by multiples of 6 numbers, in your case it's followed by only one and a spurious minus sign, hence the error message.